# Using Processing qgis:extractbylocation?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I try to use the processing 'qgis:extractbylocation' in QGIS 2.8.2 from the QGIS algorithm provider

```
  #Récupérer tous les départements qui s'intersectent avec la zone d'étude
    res=processing.runalg('qgis:extractbylocation', departementLayer, layerZone, u'intersects', 0,None)
    #Créer une couche vector issue de l'extraction des départements dans la zone
    departementLayer=QgsVectorLayer(res['OUTPUT'], "Departement(s) dans la zone d'etude", "ogr")
    # QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(departementLayer)  
    #Définir un ecodage Windows compatible avec le français
    departementLayer.setProviderEncoding(u'iso-8859-1')
    #Modifier l'encoage
    departementLayer.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'iso-8859-1')
    #Vérifier que le couche est valide sinon afficher que la couche est erronée
    if not departementLayer.isValid():
        print "Layer failed to load!"
    #QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(departementLayer)  
    #Modifier la barre de procession à 11%
    self.dlg.progressBar.setValue(11)
```

however when, i run the application , it gives not just the districts(departemets) inside the layerzone but also those that are next to the layerzone . My question is : what processissing can i use to have just the ditricts(departement)inside the layer zone ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Is there a particular reason you are using a very outdated GIS-version?

Comment: Thanks, no there is no particulat reason. i just got used to it

Comment: Then you might try an update first?

Comment: What about `u'within'`?

Comment: When i use u'within' , it gives me 0 result

Comment: For the update , the application works only on QGIS 2.8.2